# Kubernetes sends traffic to the pod even after sending SIGTERM

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a SpringBoot project with graceful shutdown configured. Deployed on k8s `1.12.7` Here are the logs,

```
2019-07-20 10:23:16.180 INFO [service,,,] 1 --- [ Thread-7] com.jay.util.GracefulShutdown : Received shutdown event
2019-07-20 10:23:16.180 INFO [service,,,] 1 --- [ Thread-7] com.jay.util.GracefulShutdown : Waiting for 30s to finish
2019-07-20 10:23:16.273 INFO [service,fd964ebaa631a860,75a07c123397e4ff,false] 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] com.jay.resource.ProductResource : GET /products?id=59
2019-07-20 10:23:16.374 INFO [service,9a569ecd8c448e98,00bc11ef2776d7fb,false] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.jay.resource.ProductResource : GET /products?id=68
...
2019-07-20 10:23:33.711 INFO [service,1532d6298acce718,08cfb8085553b02e,false] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] com.jay.resource.ProductResource : GET /products?id=209
2019-07-20 10:23:46.181 INFO [service,,,] 1 --- [ Thread-7] com.jay.util.GracefulShutdown : Resumed after hibernation
2019-07-20 10:23:46.216 INFO [service,,,] 1 --- [ Thread-7] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Application has received the `SIGTERM` at `10:23:16.180` from Kubernetes. As per [Termination of Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods) `point#5` says that the terminating pod is removed from the endpoints list of service, but it is contradicting that it forwarded the requests for 17 seconds (until `10:23:33.711`) after sending `SIGTERM` signal. Is there any configuration missing?

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim
MAINTAINER Jay

RUN apt update && apt install -y curl libtcnative-1 gcc && apt clean

ADD build/libs/sample-service.jar /

CMD ["java", "-jar" , "sample-service.jar"]
```

`GracefulShutdown`

```
// https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4657
class GracefulShutdown(val waitTime: Long, val timeout: Long) : TomcatConnectorCustomizer, ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {

    @Volatile
    private var connector: Connector? = null

    override fun customize(connector: Connector) {
        this.connector = connector
    }

    override fun onApplicationEvent(event: ContextClosedEvent) {

        log.info("Received shutdown event")

        val executor = this.connector?.protocolHandler?.executor
        if (executor is ThreadPoolExecutor) {
            try {
                val threadPoolExecutor: ThreadPoolExecutor = executor

                log.info("Waiting for ${waitTime}s to finish")
                hibernate(waitTime * 1000)

                log.info("Resumed after hibernation")
                this.connector?.pause()

                threadPoolExecutor.shutdown()
                if (!threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    log.warn("Tomcat thread pool did not shut down gracefully within $timeout seconds. Proceeding with forceful shutdown")

                    threadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow()

                    if (!threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        log.error("Tomcat thread pool did not terminate")
                    }
                }
            } catch (ex: InterruptedException) {
                log.info("Interrupted")
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
            }
        }else
            this.connector?.pause()
    }

    private fun hibernate(time: Long){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time)
        }catch (ex: Exception){}
    }

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GracefulShutdown::class.java)
    }
}
@Configuration
class GracefulShutdownConfig(@Value("\${app.shutdown.graceful.wait-time:30}") val waitTime: Long,
                             @Value("\${app.shutdown.graceful.timeout:30}") val timeout: Long) {

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GracefulShutdownConfig::class.java)
    }

    @Bean
    fun gracefulShutdown(): GracefulShutdown {

        return GracefulShutdown(waitTime, timeout)
    }

    @Bean
    fun webServerFactory(gracefulShutdown: GracefulShutdown): ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory {

        log.info("GracefulShutdown configured with wait: ${waitTime}s and timeout: ${timeout}s")

        val factory = TomcatServletWebServerFactory()
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(gracefulShutdown)
        return factory
    }
}
```

`deployment file`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: service
  name: service
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 420
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: service
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 2
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: service
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: dev
        image: service:2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 20
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        name: service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 60
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 100
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
```

**UPDATE:**

Added custom health check endpoint

```
@RestControllerEndpoint(id = "live")
@Component
class LiveEndpoint {

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LiveEndpoint::class.java)
    }

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var gracefulShutdownStatus: GracefulShutdownStatus

    @GetMapping
    fun live(): ResponseEntity<Any> {

        val status = if(gracefulShutdownStatus.isTerminating())
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()
        else
            HttpStatus.OK.value()

        log.info("Status: $status")
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).build()
    }
}
```

Changed the `livenessProbe`,

```
  livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /actuator/live
      port: 8080
    initialDelaySeconds: 100
    periodSeconds: 5
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    failureThreshold: 3
```

Here are the logs after the change,

```
2019-07-21 14:13:01.431  INFO [service,9b65b26907f2cf8f,9b65b26907f2cf8f,false] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.jay.util.LiveEndpoint          : Status: 200
2019-07-21 14:13:01.444  INFO [service,3da259976f9c286c,64b0d5973fddd577,false] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.jay.resource.ProductResource   : GET /products?id=52
2019-07-21 14:13:01.609  INFO [service,,,] 1 --- [       Thread-7] com.jay.util.GracefulShutdown      : Received shutdown event
2019-07-21 14:13:01.610  INFO [service,,,] 1 --- [       Thread-7] com.jay.util.GracefulShutdown      : Waiting for 30s to finish
...
2019-07-21 14:13:06.431  INFO [service,002c0da2133cf3b0,002c0da2133cf3b0,false] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.jay.util.LiveEndpoint          : Status: 500
2019-07-21 14:13:06.433  INFO [service,072abbd7275103ce,d1ead06b4abf2a34,false] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] com.jay.resource.ProductResource   : GET /products?id=96
...
2019-07-21 14:13:11.431  INFO [service,35aa09a8aea64ae6,35aa09a8aea64ae6,false] 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] com.jay.util.LiveEndpoint          : Status: 500
2019-07-21 14:13:11.508  INFO [service,a78c924f75538a50,0314f77f21076313,false] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.jay.resource.ProductResource   : GET /products?id=110
...
2019-07-21 14:13:16.431  INFO [service,38a940dfda03956b,38a940dfda03956b,false] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] com.jay.util.LiveEndpoint          : Status: 500
2019-07-21 14:13:16.593  INFO [service,d76e81012934805f,b61cb062154bb7f0,false] 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] com.jay.resource.ProductResource   : GET /products?id=152
...
2019-07-21 14:13:29.634  INFO [service,38a32a20358a7cc4,2029de1ed90e9539,false] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] com.jay.resource.ProductResource   : GET /products?id=191
2019-07-21 14:13:31.610  INFO [service,,,] 1 --- [       Thread-7] com.jay.util.GracefulShutdown      : Resumed after hibernation
2019-07-21 14:13:31.692  INFO [service,,,] 1 --- [       Thread-7] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

With the `livenessProbe` of 3 failures, kubernetes served the traffic for 13 seconds after liveness failures i.e., from `14:13:16.431` to `14:13:29.634`.

**UPDATE 2:**
The sequence of events (thanks to `Eamonn McEvoy`)

```
seconds | healthy | events
   0    |    ✔    |   * liveness probe healthy
   1    |    ✔    |   - SIGTERM
   2    |    ✔    |   
   3    |    ✔    |   
   4    |    ✔    |   
   5    |    ✔    |   * liveness probe unhealthy (1/3)
   6    |    ✔    |   
   7    |    ✔    |   
   8    |    ✔    |   
   9    |    ✔    |   
   10   |    ✔    |   * liveness probe unhealthy (2/3)
   11   |    ✔    |   
   12   |    ✔    |   
   13   |    ✔    |   
   14   |    ✔    |   
   15   |    ✘    |   * liveness probe unhealthy (3/3)
   ..   |    ✔    |   * traffic is served       
   28   |    ✔    |   * traffic is served
   29   |    ✘    |   * pod restarts
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SIGTERM isn't putting the pod into a terminating state immediately. You can see in the logs your application begins graceful shutdown at 10:23:16.180 and takes >20 seconds to complete. At this point, the container stops and pod can enter the terminating state.

As far as kubernetes is concerned the pod looks ok during the graceful shutdown period. You need to add a liveness probe to your deployment; when it becomes unhealthy the traffic will stop.

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 100
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Update:

This is because you have a failure threshold of 3, so you are allowing traffic for up to 15 seconds after the sigterm;

e.g.

```
seconds | healthy | events
   0    |    ✔    |   * liveness probe healthy
   1    |    ✔    |   - SIGTERM
   2    |    ✔    |   
   3    |    ✔    |   
   4    |    ✔    |   
   5    |    ✔    |   * liveness probe issued
   6    |    ✔    |       .
   7    |    ✔    |       .
   8    |    ✔    |       .
   9    |    ✔    |       .
   10   |    ✔    |   * liveness probe timeout - unhealthy (1/3)
   11   |    ✔    |   
   12   |    ✔    |   
   13   |    ✔    |   
   14   |    ✔    |   
   15   |    ✔    |   * liveness probe issued
   16   |    ✔    |       .
   17   |    ✔    |       .
   18   |    ✔    |       .
   19   |    ✔    |       .
   20   |    ✔    |   * liveness probe timeout - unhealthy (2/3)
   21   |    ✔    |   
   22   |    ✔    |   
   23   |    ✔    |   
   24   |    ✔    |   
   25   |    ✔    |   * liveness probe issued
   26   |    ✔    |       .
   27   |    ✔    |       .
   28   |    ✔    |       .
   29   |    ✔    |       .
   30   |    ✘    |   * liveness probe timeout - unhealthy (3/3)
        |         |   * pod restarts
```

This is assuming that the endpoint returns an unhealthy response during the graceful shutdown. Since you have `timeoutSeconds: 5`, if the probe simply times out this will take much longer, with a 5 second delay between issuing a liveness probe request and receiving its response. It could be the case that the container actually dies before the liveness threshold is hit and you are still seeing the original behaviour

Comment: Thanks. Please check the update, traffic is served even after reaching livenessProbe failures.

Comment: Please see that pod restart begins at 29th second, not at 16th second. Added sequence of events.

Comment: @jaks I've updated the timeline to account for the timeouts you have configured

Comment: Actually I am delaying the shutdown process by 30s, in the meantime I want k8s to drain the requests, so that I can gracefully shutdown the pod. If k8s keep on sending traffic, there will not be graceful shutdown and there will be an API failure. Can you suggest where I can find the traffic forwarding conditions in k8s? Any where I can check the logs and verify that probes are timing out ?

Comment: I think its a wrong approach, try instead, setting `terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30` on your container. Instead of sending SIGTERM yourself, just delete the pod. K8  will immediately set the Terminating state, stop traffic, send SIGTERM, and wait for 30 seconds before forcefully removing the pod. I think this is what you want.
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace

Comment: Actually I am not sending SIGTERM, I was doing the deployment and k8s was sending SIGTERM. In the pod receiving the closing event and delaying the shutdown process by 30s. In the meantime waiting for k8s to drain the pod.

Comment: Finally found the reason from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43576. Due to distributed in nature, the loadbalancer might not have been updated with the pod removal, it tend to send the traffic.